# Marking image by their co-ordinates

Tags: python, image

First of all I'm new to imaging, so I did a lot of research but found close to no related answer. I have co-ordinates of multiple images. I want a way to know if there's any way I can use those coordinates to put a mark [like- x, o] on the images.

list of specific coordinates of single image -

```
297 50
1404 321
1034 835
967 911
1063 935
```

I want to find out if there's any way I can use these coordinates to mark specific areas on my image. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is too broad. However, since you tagged the question with `python`, I assume that you want to do all this in python.

### Use [opencv-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)

###### Firstly, do some research on the methods that might be used:

1. [cv2.circle()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf10604b069374903dbd0f0488cb43670)

   ```
    cv.circle(img, center, radius, color[, thickness[, lineType[, shift]]]) -> img
   ```
2. [cv2.putText()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576)

   ```
    cv.putText(img, text, org, fontFace, fontScale, color[, thickness[, lineType[, bottomLeftOrigin]]]) -> img
   ```

###### Secondly, install opencv package:

```sh
pip install opencv-python
```

###### Thirdly, begin coding:

```py
import cv2


image_names = [
    './image_1.jpg',
    './image_2.jpg',
    './image_3.jpg']

li_coords = [
    [(297, 50), (1404, 321), (1034, 835), (967, 911), (1063, 935)],
    [(297, 50), (1404, 321), (1034, 835), (967, 911), (1063, 935)],
    [(297, 50), (1404, 321), (1034, 835), (967, 911), (1063, 935)]]

_GOLD = (0, 215, 255)


def draw_mark(cv_src, coord, mark_type='circle'):
    if mark_type == 'circle':
        cv_src = cv2.circle(
            cv_src, coord, radius=5, color=_GOLD, thickness=1)
    elif mark_type == 'cross':
        cv_src = cv2.putText(
            cv_src, 'x', coord,
            fontFace=cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, fontScale=1,
            color=_GOLD, thickness=1, lineType=cv2.LINE_AA)
    return cv_src


for idx, s_image in enumerate(image_names):
    cv_image = cv2.imread(s_image)
    cv_mark = cv_image.copy()  # ensure the source image unchanged
    mark_type = 'circle'
    for coord in li_coords[idx]:
        cv_mark = draw_mark(cv_mark, coord, mark_type)
        cv2.imwrite(f'./mark_{mark_type}_{idx}.jpg', cv_mark)
```

Before running, replace the `image_names` list with real image names. The `li_coords` should store the co-ordinates to be drawn on each image.

After running, the marked images will show up in current folder, as the below.

| mark_circle_0.jpg | mark_cross_0.jpg |
| --- | --- |
| [image: mark_circle_0] | [image: mark_cross_0] |

> View the images in new tabs to check the marks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wanted to know one more thing since you have taken multiple images here, what if multiple images have different co-ordinates each then do we need to run a for-loop for that.

Comment: Hi @siyar, I don't understand the meaning of 'different co-ordinates'? Does it mean the shapes (heights and widths) of images? Or does it mean the co-ordinates of marks you want to draw?

Comment: Like for a particular image there are more than 1 co-ordinates listed in separate file. For eg- there's a picture of apple tree and the co-ordinates of apples hanging from the tree are given in separate file. For all images there are separate dedicated files containing the co-ordinates.

Comment: I see now. Yes, you need to run **double loops** for drawing multiple co-ordinates on multiple images separately. The first for-loop will iterate over all `apple trees`, the second for-loop should iterate over all `apples` of current tree. I will update the answer in a short time.

Comment: Thanks... Will try and check the results.